# NodeJS Express Get URL Params when doing POST

Tags: node.js, express

How do I get the param in the url when I make a POST?

For example, I am in chat page. The chat url is localhost:3000/chat/abc

In the chat page, I making a POST request to /sendchat.
In that POST, I would like to include the 'abc' params too.

(req.params.id)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same way you do in every other express middleware.

Let's assume you have a route defined like this:

```
app.post('/chat/:id', (req, res) => {
   // your code here
})
```

Also assuming that:

- your app correctly parses json-encoded requests;
- your app listens to localhost:3000;

If you make a call like this:

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"username":"whites11" }' localhost:3000/chat/test?foo=bar
```

You can get:

- The chat ID with:

  `req.params.id`
- The `foo` get parameter with:

  `req.query.foo`
- The parsed body with:

  `req.body`